# Structuring Complex Tabular Data for lookup in swift

Tags: swift, oop, data-structures

Sorry for the poor descriptive title, but I could not think of a better way to phrase it.

I want to convert a table of data into an app where I can input different parameters and it will compute the result for me. I managed to make this work in Python, but now I'd like to create an iOS app for it.

I am having a tough time determining how I should structure my data. I have the data in excel format. The table structure looks like this (it is much larger):

[image]

In real world use, you would take your weight and brakes on speed to enter the table and come up with an energy value based on the temperature and pressure altitude.

In python, I used a pandas dataframe and broke them down by weight and used hierarchical indices to search for the energy value.

For my app, I have been struggling with the OOP concept of how to structure my data for use. I have thought about creating a weight object, with different brakes on speed properties. Each property would have a dictionary of Pressure altitudes whose values would be a nested dictionary of temperature and the computed energy value. This makes sense to me, but then I will have to create all the data manually as the table is fairly large, so it seems time consuming. It is also not reusable in other applications.

I cannot determine if a database like SQLite, realm or core data would be more beneficial to internal object. I will also run into the problem of how to import the data in each database. I also have the issue of multiple subtables where the x and y index matter.

There is a large amount of data, so creating the nested dictionaries would take some time by hand, and get very complex. I'm not sure what the best practice would be for dealing with a table where you need to match multiple indices for a value.

Can someone point in the right direction of how you would structure your data and what the best practice would be?

EDIT for clarification: The inputs I will receive are Weight, Brakes on Speed, and Temperature. Using these values, the program should determine the brake energy from the chart.

I am also not opposed to building all the classes with nested dictionaries manually, even though it would be time consuming; I just do not want to structure it this way if it is not a good practice, and there are better methods used.

Comment: What kind of look-up do you need to support? What're the inputs, and what are the outputs?

Comment: Everything would be an input and the output would be the energy which is expressed as a float number in the table.

For example the input would be the weight, brakes on speed, temperature and pressure altitude and this would be searched to output a single energy number.

Comment: So `(Weight, BrakesOnSpeed, Temp, Pressure, Altitude) -> Energy`? Are there any other kind of look ups you need?

Comment: "so creating the nested dictionaries would take some time by hand, and get very complex" But you entered the data into your Python program by hand, right? Why is that less time consuming?

Comment: Alexander, you are correct. There are no other lookups.

Comment: Sweeper, I imported the excel spreadsheet into a pandas dataframe, so I did not enter it all manually.

Comment: flatten the data out into one dataframe with the following columns: Weight, BrakesOnSpeed, Temp, Pressure, Altitude and Energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flattened out the data as Golden Lion suggested and it worked as intended.